# Too many threads are Blocked in sync method cxf-core

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

Hi, While giving 300 concurrent request to SOAP webservice some considerable number of threads are **BLOCKED** in `org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl.configureBean(ConfigurerImpl.java:132)`

Inside that class method `configureBean` is sync.

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1483' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" #162920 daemon prio=5 os_prio=64 tid=0x000000013b64d800 nid=0x27d93 waiting for monitor entry [0xfffffffda4afe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl.configureBean(ConfigurerImpl.java:132)
    - waiting to lock  (a org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl)
    at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl.configureBean(ConfigurerImpl.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.configureObject(ServiceImpl.java:568)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.configureObject(ServiceImpl.java:562)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createDispatch(ServiceImpl.java:696)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createDispatch(ServiceImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createDispatch(ServiceImpl.java:714)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.createDispatch(Service.java:503)
```

Can any one help me to over come this problem ?? because of this overall performance is getting down while deploying in weblogic server

Thanks

Comment: Did one small work around for this problem like, Create dispatch object in singletone and make use of same object for all request.

Comment: could you provide an example of creation and usage of Dispatch ?